# What to look for in indoor sports shoes?

Tags: running-shoes, shoes

I'm looking to get shoes for indoor sports (like squash, badminton or just running). What should I look for when shopping these kinds of shoes?

Answer (score 3):

For me, what I look for is practicality. Do they have good grip, are they comfortable and how much weight the shoe has.

The grip for those sorts of sports 100% has to be good, otherwise you're going to be at a disadvantage.

How comfortable the shoes are is pretty self explanatory, you don't want to be doing sports with an uncomfortable feeling from your clothing/footwear.

Most importantly the weight, I like for my shoes to be quite light for indoor as they aren't really going to be coming into contact with anything environmental nor are they going to be needed for heavy duty. The shoes being light can give you a slight advantage in performance in terms of being able to move your feet that slight bit quicker although mostly doesn't affect the overall scenario.